# Java - Drools validate list of object values

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine

I want to my Drool generic one.
This is my Java class structure:

```
public class RulesModel {
private String field;
private List<Object> values;
public String getField() {
    return field;
}
public void setField(String field) {
    this.field = field;
}
public List<Object> getValues() {
    return values;
}
public void setValues(List<Object> values) {
    this.values = values;
}
}
```

And I want my rule like below:

```
rule "sample"
when
    $rule : RulesModel( field == "source", value == "facebook", value == "youtube", value != "instagram" )  
then
    // actions
end
```

How to validate list objects in Drools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for are the `contains` and `not contains` operators:

(Assuming that your `RuleModel` contains `Strings` as values)

```
rule "sample"
when
    $rule : RulesModel( field == "source", values contains "facebook", values contains "youtube", value not contains "instagram" )  
then
    // actions
end
```

You can get more information about Drools' supported operators here: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.37.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#drl-operators-ref_drl-rules

Hope it helps,

Comment: how to validate multiple field  in  RulesModel.? If i pass the list of RulesModel then it should validate     `$rule : RulesModel( field == "source", values contains "facebook")  && $rule : RulesModel( field == "createdBy", values contains "admin")`. But i don't know how to change rules.

Comment: Please post this as a new question with a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have created a new question [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056120/java-generic-drools-rule

Comment: i would compare list of RuleModel objects in a single time.  `$rule : RulesModel( field == "source", values contains "facebook") && $rule2 : RulesModel( field == "createdBy", values contains "admin") && $rule3 : RulesModel( field == "priority", values > 10)` @Esteban Aliverti